# How do i get these cracks to disappear?

Tags: rendering

How do i get these dreaded cracks in this sphere to go away? By the way i'm using the cell fracture add on to make a building crack when hit. I've tried to use the subsurf modifier but i am kind of a noob at blender. So can i get these cracks to go away? or am i approaching this animation the wrong way?[image]

Comment: "This animation"... means nothing if you don't explain or show a little more...  and only guessing is left. Should the ball crack and be destroyed when it touches the "ground?". maybe you can hide the cracked version of the ball, show the good looking one, then at impact time swap their visibility and let the cracked one destroy in pieces...

Comment: Yea this animation im talking about is a big city building, just sitting there, then something like a asteroid or a ball crashes into it and it just falls to pieces

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Cell fracture addon, there is an option called `Margin`. It sets the space ('cracks') between the fractals. If you see these cracks, the reason may be that your Margin is set too high.
[image: setting the gap size]
Ensure, that it is not too small, because otherwise the physics engine thinks that the parts are intersecting each other, calculate a repelling force and this will tear the the ball apart.